# Netbeans freezes on startup at ubuntu17.10

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

Does anybody know "java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop"? After new Install of Ubuntu 17.10 (xfce), OpenJava1.8., Netbeans freezes while showing the splash. Other Java Apps run properly.  ~./.netbeans/8.2/var/log/messages.log shows:

> ---
>
> > Log Session: Wednesday, November 29, 2017 3:02:48 PM CET
> >     System Info:    Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)   Operating System        = Linux
> >     version 4.13.0-17-generic running on amd64   Java; VM; Vendor        =
> >     1.8.0_151; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.151-b12; Oracle Corporation   Runtime                 = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
> >     1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12   Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre   System Locale; Encoding =
> >     de_DE (nb); UTF-8   Home Directory          = /home/ralph   Current
> >     Directory       = /home/ralph   User Directory          =
> >     /home/ralph/.netbeans/8.2   Cache Directory         =
> >     /home/ralph/.cache/netbeans/8.2   Installation            =
> >     /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/nb
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/ide
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/extide
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/java
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/apisupport
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/websvccommon
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/profiler
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/harness
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/javafx
> >                                 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform
>
> [..]
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor:
>   DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32   at
>   java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:135)     at
>   java.awt.dnd.DragSource.(DragSource.java:148) Caused:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.DnDSupport.(DnDSupport.java:118)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.ToolbarConfiguration.dndSupport(ToolbarConfiguration.java:132)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.ToolbarConfiguration.refresh(ToolbarConfiguration.java:312)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.ToolbarConfiguration.activate(ToolbarConfiguration.java:400)
>     at org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool.activate(ToolbarPool.java:245)   at
>   org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool.setConfigurationNow(ToolbarPool.java:329)
>     at org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool.setConfiguration(ToolbarPool.java:301)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.showWindowSystem(DefaultView.java:567)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.windowSystemVisibilityChanged(DefaultView.java:542)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.changeGUI(DefaultView.java:187)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.dispatchRequest(ViewRequestor.java:275)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.processVisibilityRequest(ViewRequestor.java:264)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.postVisibilityRequest(ViewRequestor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.scheduleRequest(ViewRequestor.java:121)
>     at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.setVisible(Central.java:140)   at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.setVisible(WindowManagerImpl.java:931)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.show(WindowSystemImpl.java:105)
>     at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:244)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
>   [catch] at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
>     at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1541)
>     at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1803)   at
>   java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:131)     at
>   java.awt.dnd.DragSource.(DragSource.java:148)     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.DnDSupport.(DnDSupport.java:118)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.ToolbarConfiguration.dndSupport(ToolbarConfiguration.java:132)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.ToolbarConfiguration.refresh(ToolbarConfiguration.java:312)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.toolbars.ToolbarConfiguration.activate(ToolbarConfiguration.java:400)
>     at org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool.activate(ToolbarPool.java:245)   at
>   org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool.setConfigurationNow(ToolbarPool.java:329)
>     at org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool.setConfiguration(ToolbarPool.java:301)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.showWindowSystem(DefaultView.java:567)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.windowSystemVisibilityChanged(DefaultView.java:542)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.changeGUI(DefaultView.java:187)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.dispatchRequest(ViewRequestor.java:275)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.processVisibilityRequest(ViewRequestor.java:264)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.postVisibilityRequest(ViewRequestor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.scheduleRequest(ViewRequestor.java:121)
>     at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.setVisible(Central.java:140)   at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.setVisible(WindowManagerImpl.java:931)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.show(WindowSystemImpl.java:105)
>     at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:244)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.awt.AWTException: Exception: class
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Width (0) and height (0) must be
>   non-zero occurred while creating cursor CopyDrop.32x32    at
>   java.awt.Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(Cursor.java:363)    at
>   sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1539)
>     ... 36 more INFO
>   [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogParser]:
>   Unpaired license 00000008 without any module.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it appears the Java Version you are running is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode)
```

According to Netbeans bugzilla, this has been reported as a bug: [Bug 257554 - RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257554)

It turns out that it is linked to a reported bug in Unity-Mir : [Java applications are missing X11 resources - XQueryBestCursor return 0,0.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-mir/+bug/1250613)

From the comments , the JDK version along with the old XMir (which is not supported anymore) was responsible of that . Anyway, it is fixed by the last XMir versions.

> This would be a bug in Java, where it is unable to deal with the Xorg
>   software cursor. Which is a problem unrelated to Mir really. Mir just
>   puts X in a (valid) mode where the bug is triggered.

Although, we could work around the Java bug by implementing full hardware cursor support in XMir...

and

> XMir 1.0 (the old Xorg extension) is now deprecated and is not being
>   maintained or fixed. It is replaced by the new 'Xmir' binary (package
>   'xmir') introduced in Ubuntu 15.10 wily.

and

> Note: The new Xmir uses the hardware cursor (where available on
>   desktop). So if this bug still exists at all, it would only be on
>   mobile (Android Mir platform).

You should consider upgrading to the "new" version of JAVA.

**A Simple Work around**

1- Edit following file:

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

2- Replace `rhgb quiet` to `nomodeset`.

3- Run on terminal: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

4- Reboot.